# Show that a function of a symmetric random walk is a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

> Suppose $S_n = (X_n,Y_n)$ is a symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Show that
>   $G_n = X_n^2 + Y_n^2 - n$ is a martingale. What is true about $E_{(x_0,y_0)}[|S_n|]$? Find an upper bound for $E_{(0,0)}[T_r]$ using optional stopping, where $T_r$ is the first time that $|S_n| \geq r$.

Here is what I have:
$$
\begin{align}
G_{n+1} - G_n &= X_{n+1}^2 + Y_{n+1}^2 - (n+1) - (X_n^2 + Y_n^2 - n)\\
&= (X_{n+1}^2 - X_n^2) + (Y_{n+1}^2 - Y_n^2) - n - 1 + n\\
&= (X_{n+1} - X_n)^2 + (Y_{n+1} - Y_n)^2 + 2X_{n+1}X_n + 2Y_{n+1}Y_n - 1
\end{align}
$$
We want to show that $E[G_{n+1} - G_n | A_v] = 0$, where $A_v = {S_n,S_{n-1},...S_0}.$
$$
\begin{align}
E[G_{n+1} - G_n | A_v] &= E[(X_{n+1} - X_n)^2|X_n] + E[(Y_{n+1} - Y_n)^2|Y_n] + 2E[X_{n+1}X_n|X_n] + 2E[Y_{n+1}Y_n|Y_n] - 1\\
&= 1 + 1 - 1 + ?
\end{align}
$$
I'm stuck here (is the above correct so far?), and not sure how to proceed with the rest of the problem.

Comment: You have a sign error on the last line of $G_{n+1}-G_n$. Namely $(X_{n+1}-X_n)^2 = X_{n+1}^2 \color{red}{+} X_n^2 - 2X_nX_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 3):

let $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_1,Y_1,\dots,X_n,Y_n)$, $\xi_{n+1}=X_{n+1}-X_{n}$ and $\eta_{n+1}=Y_{n+1}-Y_n$.
Then,
$$
G_{n+1}=X_{n}^2+2X_{n}\xi_{n+1}+\xi_{n+1}^2+Y_{n}^2+2Y_{n}\eta_{n+1}+\eta_{n+1}^2-n-1,$$ hence $$G_{n+1}=G_{n}+2X_{n}\xi_{n+1}+2Y_{n}\eta_{n+1}+\xi_{n+1}^2+\eta_{n+1}^2-1.
$$
One knows that $G_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable, that $\xi_{n+1}$ and $\eta_{n+1}$ are independent of $\mathcal{F}_n$, that $E[\xi_{n+1}]=E[\eta_{n+1}]=0$, and that $E[\xi_{n+1}^2]+E[\eta_{n+1}^2]=1$, hence
$$E[G_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=G_n+2X_{n}E[\xi_{n+1}]+2Y_{n}E[\eta_{n+1}]+E[\xi_{n+1}^2]+E[\eta_{n+1}^2]-1=G_n.
$$
Thus, $(G_n)$ is a martingale with respect to the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)$.

By the way, I guess that the random walk you mean is simple random walk because the result is not true for every random walk, just check that the expectation of $G_{n+1}$ is not equal to $G_{n}$ in general.